# java Matcher need to know if subsequence equals whole sequence

Tags: java, regex

I need to figure out a way to determine when the thing being match isn't a subseq but is the whole sequence. ex. "this" not "is".

```
        while (in.hasNextLine()) {
            count++;
            String patternInLine = in.nextLine().toString();
            m = p.matcher(patternInLine);
            if (m.find() && searchPattern.equals(m.group())) {
                System.out.println("matches group: " + m.group());
                m.toString();
                System.out.println(patternInLine);
                foundLinePattern.get(file).add(patternInLine);

            }

        }
        in.close();

    }
```

Comment: What's your current regex?

Comment: Does `m.toString();` do anything useful?

Comment: Sorry the code got cut off  Pattern.compile(searchPattern); is called out side of the while. And toString() isn't offering any purpose other then to test. I think I might of found a way to tell if its a substring i'll just call length on m.group and compare to what was read in the from the scanner. I was just wondering if there was a method to figure this out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `m.matches()` instead of `m.find()`.

`find` looks for any substring that matches your regex.

`matches` tries to match only the whole string against the regex. It will not look for substrings.

Comment: Both of your answer have helped but I am still struggling to get the exact string to match while still preserving the whole line. The test case i am  using is searching the word "is"   and once I find it I want to print  the whole line. It was finding "this" for my "is" search. the m.matches works when i use Scanner::next(), but then I can't save the whole line to print it. The program is a ghetto version of grep on linux.

Comment: @user3216331 Then it sounds like your question was poorly worded. You aren't asking how to match on a whole sequence; you are asking how to write a regular expression that only detects whole words.

Comment: You're Correct,  sorry  about the confusion the regex is  very basic  it's more about the Matcher methods

Comment: There is no Matcher method for "match whole words only".